What is this spring for from the rear wheel?
I am trying to take off the magnet light holder from my rear wheel and this spring popped out when removing the red plastic screw and now I can't fit it back in. What is it for? Gears are SRAM S7



I'm guessing the second photo is the left-hand side of your bike but its upside down?

Did you unscrew the red plastic plug or did it just fall out while you were working elsewhere on the bike ?

Lastly, please add a photo of your magnetic light holder with [edit]

@Criggie It's a closeup by I managed to fix it back in by holding it tight with a small tool, don't know the name in English. I didn't remove the magnet thought, didn't want to mess anything up

This page https://www.rideyourbike.com/sramIGH.shtml has good diagrams (you just need to find your own adventure from them :)). The spring pushes the internal gear selector rod back out when the cable is loosened.
Looks like there isn't an easy way to put it in. Find a long thin rod that fits inside the spring and put the rod in the axle so that it guides the spring while you push it. Then carefully hold the spring in while you screw the red cap. Important! Remember to close your eyes before the spring accidentally jumps out! Or wear safety glasses.

I luckily managed to fix the problem. Thanks for the diagrams, I'll use them if I decide to pull it apart some other time!
